# Foursquare delete request

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm SU2 at foursquare. And I try to figure out how to delete request progressing. Some times I make delete request and other SU in my community can't see. But some times they see delete request which is not make by any SU.

Is anybody have any Idea about the progress. Our community think like (I dont know where are they know) for delete request it's need 4 point. And point bacis by your SU level (SU2=2,SU3=3)

Answer (score 0):

We built a smart system that takes various factors into account when SUs review and resolve flagged venues or flagged edits. The exact parameters are always being tweaked so, they can and will change over time.